# A riddle that needs crackin'!

Tags: riddle

I move rather oddly, my legs kinda suck
At least I have more than the average shmuck
A curse will make two of me, minus the head
But without the head I, of course, will be dead

A chicken being choked while wearing a suit
(A triple entendre! And two of them lewd...)
He knows me well, I'm embarassed to say
If you haven't yet met him, stay far away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer for the first stanza:

> octopus

I move rather oddly, my legs kinda suck

> yeah, looks [kinda odd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37p4U.jpg); octopus limbs have suction cups

At least I have more than the average shmuck

> An octopus has eight limbs

A curse will make two of me, minus the head

> A hex is a curse, but also a nickname for the hexadecimal system, which uses base-16 numbers; 16 happens to be the number of limbs two (headless) octopodes have.

But without the head I, of course, will be dead

> Just like most other animals.

---

The second stanza has me completely stumped, though.

Comment: Very nice! You are correct. 
The second stanza stumping you is probably something to be proud of, haha. It even admits it's a bit embarrassing and suggests staying away.

"another word for chicken" + "clothing that chokes" is well known for... ahem... "featuring" this

Answer (score 3):

> I move rather oddly, my legs kinda suck 
>   At least I have more than the average shmuck
>   A curse will make two of me, minus the head
>   But without the head I, of course, will be dead

@Bass explained this verse already...

> Sounds like an 8-tentacled sea creature, the obvious answer is an octopus.

The second verse...

> A chicken being choked while wearing a suit
>   (A triple entendre! And two of them lewd...)

I believe this means:

> A chicken is *hen*, and the thing that 'chokes' you when you are wearing a suit is a *tie*, so this must refer to *Hentai*?

The title "A riddle that needs *crackin*!"

> Sounds like *Kraken* - a legendary octopus-like sea monster. Also something you wouldn't like to meet

Also...

> I noted that you responded to me in Pirate speak, and The Kraken features in *The Pirates of The Caribbean*.

So is the entire answer:

> *Octopus Hentai*? Or *Tentacle Hentai*? I kind of wish I'd never started this one...

Comment: Yarr, matey, afraid ye be a bit off with the second stanza and title. The title clue be a bit more spooky than a mere egg, curse it to the briny depths whence it came from!

Comment: Aha! You got the title! The second stanza is not related to it though. You can see my comment to @Bass for a hint.

Comment: Haha, cock was actually the mislead. Try hen. And something around the neck that's most commonly worn with suits.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second stanza is

> Hentai - a hen, being choked by a tie while  wearing a suit... also, the Japanese word for erotic comics/animation.

Comment: Oh... So... If it's combined with the first stanza... It will become... Hmm...

Comment: This answer was rather.... passionate ;)

Comment: You guys! The answer is just the creature. The second stanza is only there to help you figure it out. Get your mind out of the gutter!